# How can I optimise this code for converting from JSON to XML?

Tags: java, xml, json, performance

I'm using this code to convert JSON to XML:

```java
DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document document = documentBuilder.newDocument();
document = standardJsonToXML(hierarchyData, document, null);
TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
DOMSource source = new DOMSource(document);
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
StreamResult result = new StreamResult(writer);

transformer.transform(source, result);

return writer.toString();
```

How can I increase its performance?

Comment: what is the programing language? it looks java to me.

Comment: Can you share with us, why exactly do you need performance? In what context it will be used?

Comment: Yes it's a java language. As I read some where handling json and xml consume more buffer space, The above code creating several instance, So my main concern is that what would be the best option for converting JSON to XMl

Comment: why do you need performance?

Comment: You do not show the method standardJsonToXML(). I suspect this is the slowest part?

Comment: Hey @eckes = standardJsonToXML() not taking much time I have analysis it through yourkit profiler, My main concern is with above mention approach I need to create more then 8 different objects and this method call many times and very frequently in our projects , Each time it's creating same object again, Which cause Frequent GC calls and that make slow my overall projects

Comment: Well, I am not sure about that assessment, the dom transformation does create IMHO even more objects (but all are easily collectible). Anyway, you can optimize it by using for example StAX instead of DOM (or you use a dom serializer directly on `document`).